# How to Have \idxlayout Not Treat \dotfill as Part of the Index Entry?

Tags: indexing, makeindex, idxlayout

I am trying to incorporate the effect of `\dotfill` in producing an Index with the `idxlayout` package.

I have tried this very (basic) approach:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
Sentence\index{Index entry1}
\newpage Another Sentence\index{Index entry2 \dotfill}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which prodices the following output for the Index:

[image]

I can see why Latex is treating `\dotfill` as part of the entry, as evidenced by the comma appearing at the end of the sequence of dots.

My QUESTION is: How may I have the comma appear after `Index entry2' followed by the sequence of dots leading to the page number?

I would like to be able to mimic somewhat, the Index from a very old book---but would like to be able to incorporate a comma.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: what is the intention of putting `\dotfill` in `\index` ??? the argument of `\index` are the terms to be indexed the formatting of the index list is specified elsewhere.

Comment: @David Carlisle To be able to replicate, reasonably well, the entries of an existing Index published over a century ago.

Comment: OK the formatting of the index list does not affect the argument of `\index`  any more than you would put formatting of a section title in `\section{...}` will post something later if noone else does

Comment: did you intend to delete the image of the intended layout?

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you, Actually, I have removed the snippet I used as it did not contain commas. But I would still like to be able to make use of a comma.

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes. Shall I put it back? (though it has no commas?)

Comment: @David Carlisle I just put it back. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting of the index is specified in the index style not via `\index` which just specifies the text to be indexed.

[image]

The separator before the page number of a top level index entry is `delim_0` which is `,` by default but you can make it `\dotfill` by having an index file say `dotted.ist` which just has the line

```
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
```

which you can reference using the `imakeidx` package you are using via the optional argument of `\makeindex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s dotted]
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
Sentence\index{Index entry1}
\newpage Another Sentence\index{Index entry2}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this; however, when I run the code as you have posted it, I get no dots at all. Am I doing something wrong? Or, perhaps is my version of latex 2.12.22 too old to handle this?

Comment: @mlchristians no anything in the last 10 years or so should be fine . check the log that the `dotted.ist` was found (or equivalently run `makeindex -s dotted yourfile` by hand after running pdflatex the first time (you need to run pdflatex again of course to typeset the generated index)

Comment: @mlchristians the terminal and log file should show `Scanning style file ./dotted.ist.done (1 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).` when you run pdflatex on your document. If you got `Index style file dotted not found.` then you did not save the index style under the correct name

Comment: Thank you for your help.